# Algorithms:Max k-cut in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, greedy

I have to develop the distributed algorithm for channel allocation in Wireless mesh network which is similar to Max K-cut problem in a graph.
I have searched a lot for an algorithm of Max k-cut problem in a graph using greedy approximation but everywhere I found the mathematical analysis only.

Would please anyone explain how we approach this problem for implementation?

Here is the link for brief description-https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54028/a-greedy-approximation-algorithm-for-max-k-cut

Comment: It might help if you describe the problem more clearly, as well as what you've found.

Comment: Thank you. I have described the question more, please have a look.